Conditional Probability of Elements found in Absorbing Markov Chain
Suppose I have an absorbing Markov chain $X_n$ with a finite set of transient states $\{t_i\}_{i=1}^{m}$. Let $c_i$ be the event that $X_n = t_i$ for some $n$. I am wondering how to find $\Pr(c_i \; | \; \bigcup_{j \in J}\,c_j)$ for some index set $J$.
I have been messing with different ways of calculating the probability, but I seem to be hitting a dead end each time. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!
